# Google App Engine: Request was aborted after waiting too long

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a small NodeJS application backend that is serving a React frontend running in a standard GAE environment which has no real world load - it only serves my personal requests when I am testing stuff.

So I was clicking through the frontend app for about an hour which sent a few requests to the backend last night and this error message suddenly popped up:

```
Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request.
```

These are my logs:

```
2021-03-11 06:30:06.228 CET GET /l/data 200
Api call succeeded. Returning data.

2021-03-11 06:30:52.859 CET
[start] 2021/03/11 05:30:52.858446 Quitting on terminated signal

2021-03-11 06:31:25.997 CET OPTIONS /l/orders 500
Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request.

2021-03-11 06:31:41.132 CET OPTIONS /l/orders 500
Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request.

2021-03-11 06:31:46.629 CET OPTIONS /l/orders 500
Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request.

2021-03-11 06:34:44.566 CET GET /l/users 200
2021-03-11 06:34:44.736 CET
[start] 2021/03/11 05:34:44.735240 No entrypoint specified, using default entrypoint: /serve
[start] 2021/03/11 05:34:44.736120 Starting app
```

From the logs I see that my previous instance was stopped prior to the requests that triggered the error and that for the new OPTIONS requests GAE did not even attempt to start an instance. Next start was triggered almost 3 minutes later.

I am still not sure what happened here and would like to understand it because I have some production services running on GAE and this makes me a bit worried.

This is my app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs12

handlers:
- url: .*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto

service: backend

automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 2

instance_class: F4
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is [article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/troubleshooter/latency#autoscaling) in documentation about it. I think this might be related with:

> The autoscaler can be configured based on the scaling characteristics of your application. These scaling parameters may become non-optimal during certain scenarios.

We do not know at all what is your app and what do you mean by "clicking" however it might cause some of those scenarios.

The same article motions that such error appears:

> in your logs, it means that the request timed out on the pending queue waiting for an idle instance.

So if this is testing app and you started to use is suddenly, it might cause short issue. I think it will not happen in constantly used app.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the responding.

The thing is, the app was being used but as per the scaling algorithm it was stopped and somehow the new requests weren't processed at all. I understand that if my app was slow to start the requests could timeout but GAE did not even try to start the app to serve the request.

I have little experience experience with GAE but I would expect it to always try to handle requests either by reloading the instance or creating a new one but here that did not happen.

Comment: I am not sure if this was some race condition where GAE thought it had an instance available but the shutdown signal was already sent so the requests were placed in the instance queue but the instance was shutdown so they were not handled. 

In that scenario scaling down to zero would mean that sometimes my requests 'rejected'.

Comment: If this is something reproducible I suggest to raise a bug on [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/community#file_feature_requests_and_defects)